# Bootstrap Django: Only show Active field in tabs

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I`ve got two tabs:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="open-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#open" role="tab" aria-controls="open" aria-selected="true">Active Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="close-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#close" role="tab" aria-controls="close" aria-selected="false">Inactive Projects</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

The Model of the Application got a field {{app.is_active}}.

Is Filtering the tab with a script is the best option to only show "Active projects" in the active tab and "Inactive projects" in the inactive tab?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

if you're not using django rest frame work.
it has a simple solution:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    {% for item in app_list %}
        {% if item.is_active %}
              <li class="nav-item active">
                   <a class="nav-link active" id="open-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#open" role="tab" aria-controls="open" aria-selected="true">{{ item }}</a>
             </li>
      {% else %}
             <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" id="close-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#close" role="tab" aria-controls="close" aria-selected="false">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I`ve tried with:  {% for project in project.all %}
        {% if project.is_active == 1 %} ......{% else  if project.isactive == 0 %} but it returns an error

Comment: it has to. because its python not c or c++, a boolean is True or False not 1/0!!. and also there's no .all after project. suppose you passed { "projects": anything_as_a_queryset } to template, then in template for loop is look like:   {% for pro in projects %}, don't blame me for your assumption